# Where's the Macro Bundle in TextMate2

Tags: textmatebundles, textmate2

I'm confused.  The Textmate manual says to record a macro you should choose Bundles -> Macro.   But there's no "Macro" on the Bundles menu in my Textmate2 installation.  And it's not that it's turned off in TextMate Preferences.  It's not in that list either.

Screen Shot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/51k7g5pxyzumzo2/Screenshot%202016-05-02%2012.47.44.png?dl=0

Clearly I'm missing something.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I read the manual.  It's not in the Bundles Menu anymore, it's in the Edit Menu.

...didn't see that in the changelist though.